# Complex Object Array Merge

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am attempting to merge 2 object arrays into a single object array while maintaining the order of `arr1` in the merged array.

Within `arr1` exists an `internalName` key that is present in `arr2`. The `type` key within `arr1` represents the key's value from `arr2` - for example, a type of `avg` in `arr1` should map to the `average` key of `arr2` with the same `internalName`.

```
const arr1 = [
  {internalName: "14_17_years_old", type: "avg"},
  {internalName: "14_17_years_old", type: "sum"},
  {internalName: "18_24_years_old", type: "avg"},
  {internalName: "25_34_years_old", type: "sum"},
  {internalName: "35_44_years_old", type: "avg"},
  {internalName: "35_44_years_old", type: "sum"},
  {internalName: "activity_attendance", type: "sum"},
];

const arr2 = [
  {average: 83, count: 7, internalName: "14_17_years_old", name: "14-17 Years Old", sum: 578},
  {average: 168, count: 11, internalName: "18_24_years_old", name: "18-24 Years Old", sum: 1850},
  {average: 193, count: 11, internalName: "25_34_years_old", name: "25-34 Years Old", sum: 2126},
  {average: 237, count: 10, internalName: "35_44_years_old", name: "35-44 Years Old", sum: 2370},
  {average: 828, count: 28, internalName: "activity_attendance", name: "Activity Attendance", sum: 23190}
];
```

Expected Result:

```
const expected = [
  {internalName: "14_17_years_old", name: "14-17 Years Old", type: "avg", value: 83},
  {internalName: "14_17_years_old", name: "14-17 Years Old", type: "sum", value: 578},
  {internalName: "18_24_years_old", name: "18-24 Years Old", type: "avg", value: 168},
  {internalName: "25_34_years_old", name: "25-34 Years Old", type: "sum", value: 2126},
  {internalName: "35_44_years_old", name: "35-44 Years Old", type: "avg", value: 237},
  {internalName: "35_44_years_old", name: "35-44 Years Old", type: "sum", value: 2370},
  {internalName: "activity_attendance", name: "Activity Attendance", type: "sum", value: 23190},
];
```

I have started down the route using a `forEach` with a nested `map`, but it returns nothing.

```
arr1.forEach((x) => {
  if (x.type === 'sum') {
    return arr2.map(y => ({
      internalName: y.internalName,
      name: y.name,
      type: 'sum',
      value: y.sum,
    }));
  }

  return arr2.map(y => ({
      internalName: y.internalName,
      name: y.name,
      type: 'avg',
      value: y.avg,
    }));
});
```

There is really a 2 part question - how can I accomplish this and do so without so much code?

Comment: `arr1.map(({ internalName, type }) => {
  const { name, [type]: value } = arr2.find(item => item.internalName === internalName);
  return { internalName, name, type, value };
});`

Answer (score 1):

You could make a lookup with `arr2` to allow constant time retrieval of the objects. Then you can `map` over the items in `arr1` and build the objects of the new result array:

```js
const arr1 = [{internalName: "14_17_years_old", type: "avg"},{internalName: "14_17_years_old", type: "sum"},{internalName: "18_24_years_old", type: "avg"},{internalName: "25_34_years_old", type: "sum"},{internalName: "35_44_years_old", type: "avg"},{internalName: "35_44_years_old", type: "sum"},{internalName: "activity_attendance", type: "sum"},];
const arr2 = [{average: 83, count: 7, internalName: "14_17_years_old", name: "14-17 Years Old", sum: 578},{average: 168, count: 11, internalName: "18_24_years_old", name: "18-24 Years Old", sum: 1850},{average: 193, count: 11, internalName: "25_34_years_old", name: "25-34 Years Old", sum: 2126},{average: 237, count: 10, internalName: "35_44_years_old", name: "35-44 Years Old", sum: 2370},{average: 828, count: 28, internalName: "activity_attendance", name: "Activity Attendance", sum: 23190}];

let lookup = arr2.reduce((map, {internalName, average:avg, sum, name }) => map.set(internalName, {avg, sum, name}), new Map)

let res = arr1.map(({internalName, type}) => ({
       internalName, 
       type, 
       value: lookup.get(internalName)[type],
       name: lookup.get(internalName)['name']
  }))

console.log(res)
```